# Can we allow users to edit a word document list fields (properties) while other users are modifying the word document itself

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, co-authoring

Inside our online document library, 2 users can edit the word document content at the same time using the co-authuring feature. but if someone is modifying a word document content and another user tried to modify the word document properties the user will get this error:-

[image]

so my question is if we can allow co-authoring between a user who is editing the word document content and another user who is editing the word document properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, editing the file property while others are editing the word document content would **prevent** you from co-authoring with others.

Comment: yes i know this,, and my question is if whether we can overcome this default behavior

Comment: I don't think we can overcome this.